# Django: Multiselect Unexpected behaviour

Tags: django

Here is my Multiselect

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label>Multiple select using select 2</label>
                        <select   class="js-example-basic-multiple w-100" id='mls' name="resources"  multiple="multiple">
                            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                            <option value="AM">America</option>
                            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
                            <option value="RU">Russia</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
```

Whenever I try to post despite selecting multiple  values I still get only one .
Here is stacktrace.

```
Variable    Value
csrfmiddlewaretoken 
'aI5tuSxOtxzGOpMDKR4RcH685yWUFpqkgTeBrYVbQ8kN9ODxnPOytllMTAb11Bib'
acc_id  
'1'
resources   
'AM'
```

I tried with getlist as well still getting single value we all can see single values are passing in request itself.

Not sure what might I am doing wrong here .

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are send single value from front.
i tested it:

```
<form method="GET">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Multiple select using select 2</label>
        <select  class="js-example-basic-multiple w-100" id='mls' name="resources"  multiple="multiple">
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            <option value="AM">America</option>
            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
            <option value="RU">Russia</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Show me markers</button>
</form>
```

i see in request:

```
"GET /test/testmarkers/?resources=WY&resources=AM HTTP/1.1" 200 1867
```

And i am sure, you are use not Form.send(). How are you send it?

Comment: I am using django form submit